# Why does this theorem not include the endpoints of f?

Tags: calculus

In this theorem, it is said the statements do not apply to the vales in the interval of f which are endpoints in the interval. I am trying to understand why this is the case. Is it because we cannot assume the function is continuous at the endpoints  and this theorem is for f being continuous on this interval?
thanks
[image]

Comment: $f(x)$ may very well by continuous at the end-points, but it is often much easier to just consider when x is in the open interval, and deal with the end-points individually. E.g consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Here it’s easier to let x be greater than 0, and take a limit for the x = 0 case.

Comment: I don't know what source this excerpt is from, but It's often convenient to consider differentiability only for open sets.

Answer (score 1):

You should read “excluding” as “not necessarily including”.

Suppose you have a function which is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. Then it satisfies being differentiable on every interval, but, with the terminology of the book, you *can* say that it's differentiable on, say, $[0,1]$ (excluding the endpoints).

To make an example for the first statement, consider $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ over the interval $[0,1]$. The function is not differentiable at $0$ (by any definition of differentiability at the endpoint of an interval), but we have $f'(x)>0$ for every $x\in(0,1)$, so we can conclude that $f$ is increasing on $[0,1]$. It *is* differentiable at $1$, but this is not of a concern.

Another way to interpret the clause “excluding the endpoints” could be “we don't mind about the function being differentiable at the endpoints, so long as it's continuous over the whole interval and differentiable in the *interior* of the interval”. By the way, the theorem doesn't state conditions on the interval: it can be open, closed or neither open nor closed.

This is useful even for functions that fail to be differentiable over an interval. Suppose $f$ is continuous over $[a,b]$, but fails to be differentiable at a single point $c\in(a,b)$ (and maybe at $a$ or $b$). If we know that $f'(x)>0$ for every $x\in(a,b)$, $x\ne c$, we can conclude as well that $f$ is increasing over $[a,b]$. Indeed, the theorem guarantees that the function is increasing over $[a,c]$ *and* over $[c,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

A function is not always differentiable in its whole domain of definition.

Take the $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ function : it is continuous in [0, 1] yet differentiable only in ]0, 1]. Here only one endpoint has to be excluded from the domain of definition to get the domain of differentiability. It is easy to construct an example where both endpoints needs to be excluded:

$$\forall x \in [0, 1], \; f(x) = \sqrt{x(1-x)}$$

$f$ is clearly continuous in $[0, 1]$ and yet only differentiable in $]0, 1[$ with:

$$\forall x\in ]0, 1[, \; f'(x) = \frac{1-2x}{2\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$$

This is an explanation of why much calculus theorem involving the derivative of some function exclude endpoints (see [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem), [Mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))).

Comment: Not a good reason: the function $x \mapsto |x|$ is not differentiable at $0$, which is not an end point. In general, a function may well be defined and continuous on an *open* subset, but still fail to be differentiable on it. The OP asks the following: given that there *exist* functions that are defined *and differentiable* on closed intervals, why are there no theorems about them in elementary calculus?